# Error reading undefined 'cut' when restarting scene in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I am working on a platformer style game in phaser 3 using arcade physics and Canvas graphics. At a point in my code I would like to completely restart the current scene, and I do so using `this.scene.restart`. Any time I attempt this it gives me the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'cut')". When using WebGl graphics it gives me another error of "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'glTexture')". Any help in knowing what this means or how to fix it would be appreciated. line 59494 for WebGl and 26816 for Canvas.

Comment: Without some code it is impossible, to say what the problem is, since on an Empty Scene `this.scene.restart` works well without any Errors. Can you provide a minimal code example, where this error occurs?

Comment: After messing around with this for a while, I still wasn't able to recreate it but I did find that if I disabled any loading graphics (progress bar) then it works fine. Is there a way to delay the preload function until the game has initialized?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how phaser works. And I'm not sure what you want to achieve. I just can assume you want to display graphics/images during the `preload`, this is not really possible. You could create a boot scene, that only loads a single small image, that you use, will you load a second scene. Or you could do something like in [this article](https://gamedevacademy.org/creating-a-preloading-screen-in-phaser-3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "load" images before the `preload` function of the scene-config, you would simply have to add the `pack` property to the `Scene` - config, and than you can use images in the `preload` function. As seen below in the demo.

***Here is the** [link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Scenes.html#.SettingsConfig__anchor)*

> *In any case, I would recommend, if you use this feature, don't load too many files, before the Scene has loaded / executed the `preload` function.*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.CANVAS,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    scene: {
        preload,
        pack: {
            files: [
                { type: 'image', key: 'logo', url: 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/phaser1.png' }
            ]
        }
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload(){
    this.add.image(200, 90, 'logo').setOrigin(.5);
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```